# Data persistence for repository and validators

Tags: java, xml, class, javabeans

In my current program, I must specify in a xml file the class that ensures the data persistence for every entity (repository) and the name of it's validator, and I have this example on how my xml file should look:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="studentService" class="service.StudentService">
        <property name="studentRepository" ref="studentRepository"/>
        <property name="disciplineRepository" ref="disciplineRepository"/>
        <property name="noteRepository" ref="noteRepository"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="studentRepository" class="repository.StudentRepository">
        <property name="validator" ref="studentValidator"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="disciplineRepository" class="repository.DisciplineRepository">
        <property name="validator" ref="disciplineValidator"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="noteRepository" class="repository.NoteRepository">
        <property name="validator" ref="noteValidator"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="studentValidator" class="domain.StudentValidator"/>
    <bean id="disciplineValidator" class="domain.DisciplineValidator"/>
    <bean id="noteValidator" class="domain.NoteValidator"/>
</beans>
```

My question is, where I can find more information about exactly this kind of implementation, or how does the code to implement this xml file in my program should look?

Comment: This looks like a Spring configuration file. Are you using Spring? Why did you choose to do that this way if you don't know how to do it?

Comment: I didn't choose it. I have a project where I should implement something like this, and I am trying to find more information about this kind of thing.

Comment: Why did the project manager, or whoever it is that made that choice, choose to do it like that? Why don't you ask him/her? And again, this just looks like a Spring file. Are you using Spring?

Comment: I am not using spring. And this is just how the thing should be done, no other way. The problem is that I should research this and do it myself, and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Sorry, but this is much too broad, and absurd. If you don't know where to start, then you should ask the person who made that choice, because he/she should know. If he/she doesn't know, then he/she's not qualidied to have made that choice in the first place.